I need a link to Leonid Shifrin's" MathProgrammingIntro.pdf" example code
I have been reading and using the Shifrin text. I tried to get the example code he mentions, but his website is closed. Anyone have a link to these examples? I ask here because this seems to be the only site he is still on.
Thanx in advance for any help.
Dennis

This was discussed at meta here

@Nasser would you mind turning this into a proper answer? I think that it can be beneficial for future visitors? ---in the meta thread other issues are discussed, so maybe a more targeted answer would be useful

@bmf hopefully Leonid Shifrin still checks this forum and I think it will be better if he would answer this. I just remembered the Meta thread when I saw this question.

Mathematica Programming: An Advanced Introduction
by Leonid Shifrin is available in PDF at

https://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=8101
https://archive.org/details/ost-computer-science-mathprogrammingintro

The Wolfram Books link links to the Internet Archive resource.
